Как сделать броню танку Unity3D
Делаю игру про танки на Unity, хочу сделать броню танка как World of Tanks, чтобы в разных частях танка была разная толщина брони. И не могу понять как вообще задать броню танку и как ее потом считывать при попадании.

Ну наверное дополнительные коллайдеры какие-то навесить в соответствующих местах и обрабатывать столкновение поражающих элементов и снарядов.

Тогда количество коллайдеров будет огромное. Я думал может как-то можно сделать карту веса как в блендере для привязки костей, и при попадании в танк определять точку попадания на карте и смотреть значение веса. Но у меня вообще нет идей как это реализовать

И в случае с коллайдерами придется делать каждый коллайдер отдельным чайлд объектом и давать скрипт содержащий данные о броне для данного коллайдера

Тебе необходимо изучить такое понятие, как Raycast и работу коллайдеров в Юнити. Они помогут тебе регистрировать попадания по твоему танку.
Ты можешь попробовать добавить Collider на различные компоненты своего танка, после чего добавить на каждый скрипт, где будешь отслеживать попадание по нему. Пример есть на сайте Unity:OnTriggerEnter

С рейкастами я знаком как и с коллайдерами. Просто я хочу найти более универсальный способ, тк настраивать каждому танку огромное количество коллайдеров выйдет довольно время затратно. Тем более танки бывают разных форм и большинству придется дополнительно моделировать ту его кучу коллайдеров.
